# Floating element in footer in final version 1.1.0 of JQM has weird behaviour

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to use the latest stable Jquery Mobile version 1.1.0 that was announced on april 13 2012. But I noticed something weird.

If I try to float a 'p' tag in the footer, the background becomes white. This is not the case if I use the 1.1.0-rc.1 version. Am I overlooking something? Because now I cant use the latest version.

This is the code, you can just copy and paste it to see it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head> 
<title>Test</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />   

<!-- New version 1.1.0 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  
<!-- New version 1.1.0 -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>    

<style type="text/css">
    p {
        float:right;
        }
</style>   
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test</h1> 
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem: use

```
text-align: right
```

instead of

```
float: right
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with jQuery Mobile version 1.1.0, the footer doesn't get the height set, so therefore the background is not visible. Your solution works for text, but not when you want to have two divs floated next to each other.

I solved it by applying this style:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```